# cannot import name '_RNNCell'

Tags: python-3.x, recurrent-neural-network

I run the following code using the pyton3:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell_impl import _RNNCell as RNNCell
```

The error was:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_RNNCell'
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the version of tf and downgrade it based on the version it is available in.